# VS2013 IISexpress issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, visual-studio

i am just making my first project in Visual Studio 2013. But when i press f5 there is error on the visual studio console

```
The program '[5740] iisexpress.exe' has exited with code -1073741816 (0xc0000008) 'An invalid handle was specified'.
```

and browser is showing error

```
Oops! Google Chrome could not connect to localhost:1311
```

can anybody help me

Comment: http://forums.iis.net/t/1196767.aspx?IISExpress+8+0+crashes+An+invalid+handle+was+specified+ This Might Help

Comment: i already try with this

Comment: maybe till we have resolution for it. you can run you app on Iss Server only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

vs2013 -> tool -> option -> project & solution-> web project -> use IIS Express 64

Hope this can help you!

Answer (score 1):

This had me hung up for over a day.  Our company just upgraded to Windows 8 and started causing this issue.  During the upgrade a new Registry Key was added

> HKCU\Software\Microsoft\IIS Express

When I removed this key IIS Express would start successfully.  The reason it was failing is because Visual Studio was getting paths confused for config files.